# How to run sudo command programmatically on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, shell

I am trying to run sudo command programmatically in my OS X app,

but i got these message

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Here is my code:

```
    NSString *runCommand(NSString *commandToRun)
    {
        NSTask *task;
        task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
        [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

        NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c" ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun], nil];


   NSLog(@"run command: %@",commandToRun);
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *output;
    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return output;
}
```

And i call this method like this :

```
runCommand(@"sudo purge");
```

Thanks for any help or sugession.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I’ve tested with `sudo echo TEST` and the output is TEST, as expected.

Comment: it could caused my os X version, i just upgraded to mavericks my OS

Comment: Does it work now that you’ve switched to Mavericks?

Comment: no it doesn't and i dont know why

Comment: I’m on Mavericks too and as I said, I’ve no problems running your code. Did it work before?

Comment: Why are you running the shell for this?!